# App or process to show Youtube videos offline without a computer?

Tags: software-recommendation, youtube, ios, network

I'm trying to avoid having to sync my iOS devices with a computer for any reason, but so far haven't been able to come up with a way to find a youtube video and cache it locally so when I leave an internet connected area I can still view it.

The methods to do it that are most common all involve a computer:

[Saving online videos (e.g. YouTube) and moving them to iPad for later offline viewing?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15775/saving-online-videos-e-g-youtube-and-moving-them-to-ipad-for-later-offline-vi)

Is there an app, or a process I can follow, that will cache youtube videos on the iOS device for viewing in a slow internet situation, or away from internet access?

Comment: Are you open to Windows software, Mac software, software as a service or do you want answers to be narrow to one particular OS running the capture software?

Answer (score 2):

[Video Downloader Pro Lite](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/video-downloader-pro-lite/id481701140?mt=8) is the app you're looking for.

> To begin a download:
>
> - Browse on the web.
> - Select any video on any website,
> - Click download.

It works pretty well for me!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using FoxTube for caching many youtube videos for offline viewing, and I just love the app.
iPhone version
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/foxtube-youtube-cache/id486365960?mt=8
iPad version
http://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/foxtube-hd-youtube-cache/id491640360?mt=8

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info.